# How to avoid Python Popen communicate() function with sqlplus from returning same headers multiple times

Tags: python, sqlplus, popen

Am using Python Popen API to connect to Oracle database via sqlplus.

My code:

```
prodMirrSession = Popen(['sqlplus','-S',prodMirrConnectString], stdin=PIPE,    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
prodMirrSession.stdin.write(sqlCommand)
prodQueryResult, prodErrorMsg = prodMirrSession.communicate()
```

In prodQueryResult, while the data of individual rows in resultSet is correct, resultSet header gets repeated multiple times. 
E.g:

```
PKD_PKG_DEF_ID||'-'||PKD_NAME||'-'||PKD_JOB_ID||'-'||PKD_OUTPUTDIR||'-'||PKD_FRE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Row 1

Row 2

Row 3

PKD_PKG_DEF_ID||'-'||PKD_NAME||'-'||PKD_JOB_ID||'-'||PKD_OUTPUTDIR||'-'||PKD_FRE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Row 4
......
```

This is not the case when using sqlplus as standalone bash shell command or via bash scripts.

Is their a way to avoid it via Popen API itself. Don't want to incur additional performance overhead in iterating the whole stdoutdata resultSet from Popen.communicate() in my Python code to filter multiple time occuring resultSet header.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good way of connecting to the db. Oracle has a perfectly good [Python interface library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle).

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman (although I've been in situations where artificial requirements are placed like 'must use sqlplus' by clients).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is due to pagesize. You can either set the page size to some very high number that exceeds your number of rows:

```
set pagesize 1000000
```

Or you can turn off headers entirely (and add them by hand or handle it by position):

```
set pagesize 0
```

Or you can use a hidden feature to only print the first header (YMMV, not sure it will always be there in the future):

```
set pagesize 0 embedded on
```

Also since I noticed you edited the question and I see the underlines... you can remove that as well (not that you asked for it, but seems like something you might want):

```
set underline off
```